# Troubleshooting "VC: Tinymce error! Compatibility with other plugins" for custom post_type

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

While using Visual Composer on a custom `post_type` you get the following error when editing a text field with a Tiny MCE wysiwyg:

```
visual composer "VC: Tinymce error! Compatibility problem with other plugins."
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to enable the '`editor`' for your custom `post_type` for WordPress to load the Tiny MCE client-side script files.

```
register_post_type( 'my_post_type', array(
[...]
'supports'           => array( 'editor')
);
```

Comment: This would be the right answer, but the question refers to a compatibility issue.

Comment: @laviku I wrote the original question? If you don't have 'editor' enabled it will throw  since there is no field to attach to.